# Spring JPA no me trae las listas en las peticiones get

Tags: api, spring-boot, jpa

El problema es que al hacer una petición get de reserva me trae todos los valores menos los que están en listas como por ejemplo las mesas que están asignadas a esa reserva.

He debugueado y los datos de la bbdd ya no le llegan a la entidad. De todas formas adjunto el servicio y el controlador también.

También he mirado las queries generadas por jpa y probandolas manualmente me han traído los datos que pedí

Mis entidades son estas:

RESERVA

```
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "reserva")
public class ReservaEntity {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "reserva_id")
  private Integer reservaId;

  @JoinColumn(name = "usuario_id")
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private UsuarioEntity usuario;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "reserva",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private Set<PistaEntity> pistas;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "reserva",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private Set<MesaEntity> mesas;

  @Column(name = "fecha_hora_inicio")
  private Date horaEntrada;

  @Column(name = "fecha_hora_final")
  private Date horaSalida;

  @Column( name = "personas")
  private Integer personas;

  @Column(name = "partidas")
  private Integer partidas;

  @Column(name = "precio_persona")
  private Float precioPersona;

}
```

MESA

```
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "mesa")
public class MesaEntity {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "mesa_id")
  private Integer mesaId;

  @Column(name = "capacidad_mesa")
  private String capacidad;

  @JoinColumn(name = "reserva_id")
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private ReservaEntity reserva;
}
```

SERVICIO

```
  @Override
  public List<ReservaDTO> findAll() {
    return reservaMapperDTO.toReservaDTOList(reservaRepository.findAll());
  }
```

CONTROLADOR

```
@GetMapping(value = "/findAll")
  public ResponseEntity <List<ReservaTO>> getAll(){
    return new ResponseEntity<>(reservaMapperTO.toReservaTOList(
        reservaService.findAll()),

        getHeader(), HttpStatus.OK);
  }
```

La salida de los datos es esta

[image: Salida de los datos en la petición]

Toda ayuda es bienvenida, muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes utilizar la técnica de carga perezosa (lazy loading), que permite cargar las entidades relacionadas sólo cuando sea necesario.

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "reserva",cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<MesaEntity> mesas;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "reserva",cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<PistaEntity> pistas;
```

Además, para asegurarse de que las entidades relacionadas se carguen correctamente cuando se accede a ellas, puede agregar los métodos get correspondientes en la entidad `ReservaEntity`:

```
public Set<MesaEntity> getMesas() {
    if (this.mesas == null) {
        this.mesas = new HashSet<>();
    }
    return this.mesas;
}

public Set<PistaEntity> getPistas() {
    if (this.pistas == null) {
        this.pistas = new HashSet<>();
    }
    return this.pistas;
}
```

Comment: Me ha funcionado. Muchisimas graciasss :))

Answer (score 1):

La solucion de @DevMind funciona pero he encontrado otra. El problema es que el @Data de lombok trae consigo un toString. Eso es lo que falla. Si se sustituye el @Data por @Getter, @Setter, @AllArgsConstructor y @NoArgsConstructor con el FetchType de las columns en LAZY, las listas ya no vienen nulas y el código en las entidades queda mas limpio. :)